# Why not fini() functions for golang package?

Tags: go, package, goroutine

There's built-in init() function for package initialization. Why not fini for destruction ? For example, I initial a goroutine pool inside my package and I want to all goroutines in the pool to finish their task before exiting instead of being forced to exit when the whole program exit.

If there's fini function. I can use sync.Wait there to fulfill my goal.

Another merit for built-in init is that it can and only can be called once，which will be my own concern if I use user-define functions as alternatives for them.

Comment: This question would probably better be rephrased as "how can I tear down my goroutine pool" with some example code and explanation of the problem. We don't design the language and can't tell you the "why there is no [..]". Besides, such an answer wouldn't really help you solve your problem ;-)

Comment: Ask yourself: When _exactly_ would such a fini function run? The moment your application receives a SIGTERM? Just before `main` returns? As part of `os.Exit`? And in which order?

Comment: Why not write your own fini, call it at the bottom of main, or use defer if main's got more than one exit point, and you can use sync.Once to ensure fini's not called more than once.

Comment: @Volker,  fini in main really solves my problem. But I just think a build-in fini would be better otherwise I have to can it explicitly, which , of course , is trivial.

Comment: @mkopriva. Good idea.  Maybe I should not be entangled with this trivial matter

Comment: Built-in magic for stuff that is trivial is dangerous. It tends to accumulate making the language more and more magical and less explicit.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    defer fini()

    wg.Add(1)
    go routine()
    fmt.Println("... in progress ... ")
}
func fini() {
    wg.Wait()
    fmt.Println("Done")
}
func init() {
    fmt.Println("Hi")
}
func routine() {
    fmt.Println("Doing somthing ...")
    time.Sleep(1000 * time.Millisecond)
    wg.Done()
}

var wg sync.WaitGroup
```

Run:

```
$ go run .
Hi
... in progress ...
Doing somthing ...
Done
```

Answer (score 0):

Doing fini in function main can solves my problem